# Bitmap z-index gdi+

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

Есть ли подобие свойства Bitmap, как в html z-index? Если один битмап попадал поверх второго, то элемент с z-index показывался вышел

Comment: Там нет dom, все отображается в том порядке, в каком оно рисуется.

Comment: @user7860670 есть ли возможность при нахождении одного элемента поверх второго, перекрывать его, кроме **SetPixel**?

Comment: Следует рисовать сначала нижний, затем верхний.

Comment: @user7860670 Понял. Еще такой вопрос: как можно узнать в какой точке пересекаются эти два объекта, точнее получить координаты пересечения